# Accessing JSON key values without loop

Tags: javascript, json

Receiving JSON response like this

```
responses = {
            "http://www.example.com/firts": {
                error: [object Object],
                response: [object Object],
                body: [object Object]
            },
            "http://www.example.com/second": {
                error: [object Object],
                response: [object Object],
                body: [object Object]
            },
            "http://www.example.com/third": {
                error: [object Object],
                response: [object Object],
                body: [object Object]
            }
        }
```

`var urls = ["http://www.example.com/firts", "http://www.example.com/second", "http://www.example.com/third"];`

It works fine in for loop like this:

```
for(url in responses) {
        var response = responses[url];
        console.log('Got the response '+response.response.statusCode);
}
```

But I am not able to access it outside for loop.
Tried:

```
var response = responses[urls[0]];
console.log('Got the response '+response.response.statusCode);
```

and

```
var response = responses["http://www.example.com/firts"];
console.log('Got the response '+response.response.statusCode);
```

and

```
var response = responses[0][urls[0]];
    console.log('Got the response '+response.response.statusCode);
```

But nothing worked for me.

Comment: Are there any additional spaces or characters you're not seeing?

Comment: Did you try (lint)[http://jsonlint.com] (trick question, not valid json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON isn't JSON. It is a set of JavaScript object literals, and when it hits `[object Object]`, it errors because you can't have `someIdentifier someOtherIdentifier` in an array literal.

Values in arrays have to be separated by commas, but it looks like you intended to have object literals there with some specific values. When you create the JavaScript, you need to express those as proper object literals instead of simply casting the objects to strings.

Comment: I am actually using `https://gist.github.com/natos/2001487` program. Not sure how would I implement the proper object literals?